# How to form data for select?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

There is a model `Provider`. It has the field `role`, which has two options: `Individual` and `Organization`. There are `summary` field and `organization` field.

It is necessary that in the `form` *(in the template)*, in the `select`, the data is displayed in the following way: if the record is associated with `Individual`, then `summqry + user`, and if with the `Organization`, then the `Organization title`.

**models.py**

```
ROLE_INDIVIDUAL = 'individual'
ROLE_ORGANIZATION = 'organization'

ROLE_CHOICES = (
    (ROLE_INDIVIDUAL, _('Individual')),
    (ROLE_ORGANIZATION, _('Organization'))
    )

class Provider(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=255, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, default=ROLE_INDIVIDUAL)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = (..., 'on_behalf', ...)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('initial').get('request')
        super(ProductCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['on_behalf'] = ModelChoiceField(queryset=Provider.objects.filter(user=user.id))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define the `__str__` method on Provider to return the string you want.

```
class Provider(models.Model):
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        if self.role == ROLE_INDIVIDUAL:
            return '{} + {}'.format(self.summary, self.user)
        else:
            return self.organization.title
```